# Is it possible to copy a Work Item Template from one project to another?

Tags: tfs

The two projects in question were created from the same base template. Essentially I've stripped out a bunch of stuff that we don't need in several of the Work Item Templates, and deleted a few others. I'd like to copy these template changes to another project, instead of redoing all the work I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other project is already created on the Server you can use the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx). The Tool you want is the Process Editor.

After you install. Fire up Visual Studio and connect to Team Explorer. Then go to Tools | Process Editor | Work Item Types | Import WIT

Select the Work Item Type template and the project you want to install it to.

or if you prefer command line solutions use witimport:

**witimport /f file /t TeamFoundationServer /p teamproject [/v] [/e encoding]**

/f        Specifies the work item type XML definition file to be imported.

/t        Specifies the name of the Team Foundation Server. This can also be a fully specified URL such as http://server:8080.

/p        Specifies the Team Project on the Team Foundation Server to which the
           file is imported.

/v        Validates the XML without importing the work item type.

/e        Specifies the name of the .NET Framework 2.0 encoding used to import
           the work item type XML.  For example, /e utf-7 will use Unicode
           (UTF-7) encoding.  Encoding is auto-detected by default where
           possible.  If unavailable, encoding defaults to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

This tool really helps with this too:
http://witsynchronizer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Nice! Although it's a bit old now. Is it because something else replaced it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes templates are located on your local machine you should be able to copy it from there. My are in Documents\Work Item Templates.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't give options to edit the process template or copy the process template